# Why are games more expensive in the EU compared to US?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Example: Smash Bros 3DS

US: $39.99
EU: €44.99 which is $57.02, **43% more** than US
UK: £39.99 which is $64.57, **61% more** than US

Where is the money going? EU taxes? Shipping? Localization?

Comment: A combination of taxes, shipping and also most importantly, average income.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK you have this thing called [VAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_tax) which NISE had to fix up [separate versions of the products](http://store.nisaeurope.com/blogs/news/15365151-vat-free-purchasing-information) on their site for counties which don't have VAT, this includes Shin Megami Tensei Persona Q for 3DS

However another problem with NISE is that they're doing a $1 = £1 conversion from NISA which is wrong but VAT is a contributor to the price since originally I could by a US Limited Edition from NISA and a standard edition of Oz Game Shop for less than a Limited Edition on NISE until VAT was removed for Australian purchases (it's like AUD $20 cheaper now)

Also don't forget there is currency conversion, $39.99 does not equal €/£39.99 and the actual amount can fluctuate based on global markets. Here are a couple of links showing how the British Point (GBP) and Euro has fluxuated over the past 10 years [US$ to £](http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=GBP&to=USD&view=10Y) - [US$ to €](http://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=EUR&to=USD&view=10Y)

As you can see in those links, the US and UK price you have listed are not the same and in the past 10 years has never been equal to the US$ or dropped below. So for every $1 in US your paying you are paying £1.61467 (as of the time posting this). If a store was to sell the game you have listed for the exact same amount as it is sold in the US, they should be selling it for ~£24.77

NOTE: I am making the assumption that the shipping costs to deliver the game to the store/warehouse from the supplier is already included in the price.

---

As for Super Smash Bros on 3DS, it is still more expensive on [Oz Game Shop](http://www.ozgameshop.com/3ds-games/super-smash-bros-game-3ds-australian-stock) in comparison to your original US Price, with the Australian Price being $51.99 in AUD $ (+$2 for postage if order is bellow $50). In the US it's $45.63 (there's a button in the top right to switch currency) however that is cheaper than the prices your showing for outside the US, so quite possibly where ever your getting these prices someone is putting their own markup on the price.

Keep in mind that the product I linked to is Australian Stock so it'll be PAL...and Nintendo is still putting Region Restriction on their games so you'll need a PAL 3DS to play it (Oz Game Shop for Region free Games will always note NTSC games and gives warning about DLC)

Comment: Those pesky markup fees... Very nice answer :)